# Which datasets are to be provided along-with patent application?

Tags: patentability, chemistry-microbiology

I am trying to patent a catalytic process (and probably the catalyst too), which I may also publish later as a research paper. However, I currently only have the reaction results - which might prove the superiority of the catalytic process. . However, the characterization results of the catalyst are still pending.

My question is, do I need to submit the characterization data of the catalyst too during the patent application or patent examination process?
Also, what type of datasets are required to prove the validity of a patent claim. If I am claiming that my catalytic process can lead to production of a specific product-do I need to submit appropriate datasets (e.g. GCMS or NMR etc) ?

I have very little idea about patent application and examination process, thus don't know how patent applications are evaluated.

Comment: Are you  planning on drafting and prosecuting the patent yourself or will you have access to an attorney. If you are academic, most universities have patent attorneys to process patents on behalf of the inventors.

Comment: Also, it can be a good idea to search for existing catalyst patents. You can learn a lot by reading them.

Comment: Than you.... it helped a lot

Comment: We will go to the patent attorney appointed by our institute. But I was going to have some basic ideas before doing that

Answer (score 1):

I am not a lawyer or a chemist, so this answer is written from the viewpoint of an inventor. You do not need extensive data sets to file a patent. Indeed I pretty much never see them. It is useful to provide plots or graphs of data supporting the function of the invention, but I doubt a patent examiner would know what to do with a data file let alone require it. Characterization data might be useful to your patent attorney when crafting claims to make sure they cover the most important ranges.